# translate is not a function (in 'translate()', 'translate' is true)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make a simple latin dictionary. I am new to JavaScript so I am trying to test the input tag with the alert function. In the console, I am receiving the error message after I click the "translate" button. Error: "translate is not a function (in 'translate()', 'translate' is true)".

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Latin Dictionary</title>
  </head>
  <h1 id="main-header">Latin Dictionary!</h1>
  <body>
    <input id="latin-word" placeholder="Latin to English"/>
    <br />
    <button onclick="translate()" id="btn-translate-latin-english">Translate</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="translate.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function translate() {
  var latinWord = document.getElementById("latin-word").value;
  alert("word that was entered: " + latinWord);
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, choose another function name, such as `myTranslate()`.

Why you can't use `translate()`? Because there's already a built-in `translate` in HTML. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp).

Note: You can choose whatever you want.

JS Code:

```
function myTranslate() {
  var latinWord = document.getElementById("latin-word").value;
  alert("word that was entered: " + latinWord);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myTranslate()" id="btn-translate-latin-english">Translate</button>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is being called because you are using the script tag after the button tag. I think moving the script into the head of the html will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the function's name `translate` which is a reserved word in JavaScript.

`translate` is a global attribute to make elements translatable or movable.

You must rename the function to fix this error. I used `Translate()`:

```js
function Translate() {
  var latinWord = document.getElementById("latin-word").value;
  alert("Word that was entered: " + latinWord);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Latin Dictionary</title>
  </head>
  <h1 id="main-header">Latin Dictionary!</h1>
  <body>
    <input id="latin-word" placeholder="Latin to English"/>
    <br />
    <button onclick="Translate()" id="btn-translate-latin-english">Translate</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="translate.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```